# Detect if any edges cross in a graph with a specified layout

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have some `Graph`s for which I have explicitly specified both the `VertexCoordinates` and the `EdgeShapeFunction`. I'd like to determine (just a boolean True/False is fine) whether the resulting `Graph` as drawn on screen contains any intersecting edges. E.g.,

[image: Image of graph with no intersecting edges, labeled False, and graph with intersecting edges, labeled True]

How might I go about detecting this?

If it is useful for testing, I produced the above graphs thusly:

```
symbols = Table[Unique[], 8];
v = Flatten[MapAt[Reverse, Table[{a, s}, {s, symbols}, {a, {-3, 3}}], {;; ;; 2}], 1];
e = BlockMap[Apply@UndirectedEdge, v, 2, 1] ~Drop~ {Length@symbols};
curv = GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> (#〚1〛〚2〛 - #〚2〛〚2〛) / #〚2〛〚1〛}]&;
g[order_] := With[{rules = Thread[symbols -> order]}, Graph[e, 
  VertexCoordinates -> Thread[v -> (v /. rules)], EdgeShapeFunction -> Thread[e -> (curv /@ e /. rules)]]]

g1 = g[{8, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6, 7}]
g2 = g[{8, 6, 5, 1, 7, 3, 2, 4}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]

ClearAll[edgeIntersections]
edgeIntersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Show @ #, 
    Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False] &;

edgeIntersections[g1]
```

> ```
>  {}
> ```

```
edgeIntersections[g2]
```

> ```
>  {{-3.99852, 4.}, {-3.31218, 3.25027}, {-3.31218, 6.74973}}
> ```

```
Show[g2, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ edgeIntersections[g2]}]]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[edgesIntersectQ]
edgesIntersectQ = edgeIntersections[#] =!= {} &;

edgesIntersectQ /@ {g1, g2}
```

> ```
> {False, True}
> ```